# Loader Plugin for Android

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I'm new to this,

I need to implement loader in phonegap android app while ajax requesting data from server till success, I searched but i did't got good plugin, so please help me or provide link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one [waiting dialog plugin](https://github.com/guidosabatini/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/WaitingDialog)

```
   // To SHOW a modal waiting dialog
window.plugins.waitingDialog.show("Your dialog text");

// To HIDE the dialog
window.plugins.waitingDialog.hide();
```

Comment: your link showing .java and .js file should i need to add those files in my project? if yes then where please little more help i need from you.

Comment: add java file to your src and js file to suitable folder here are more plugins https://github.com/guidosabatini/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android you can follow any plugin steps to intergrate this plugin to your app

Comment: i added .js AND .JAVA FILE BUT, IN .JAVA FILE I ADDED IN SRC FOLDER AS SEPRATED ITS SHOWING ERROR, should i not add it as seprate file ?or copy paste the text into the .java file